# Passing Entry widget as argument to signal handler in Gtkmm

Tags: gtk, glade, gtkmm, gtkentry

I have created glade file GUI.glade and i want to submit the content of the Entry widget on clicking the button using Gtkmm. I made the pointer to entry widget global so that i can access it in signal handler. Can i pass the entry widget as argument to the signal handler?

Comment: Yes you should be able to do that. The common approach is not that someone "gives you the code". Typically the question asker provides a (preferably compilable and small) code example, and shows what they have tried. Then someone can point out where the problem is.

Comment: Ya sorry i was asking for code of demo example but i put wrong words here.I got it how to do that . Using bind() v can bind the arguments.for example :if(pButton)
    {
      pButton->signal_clicked().connect( sigc::bind<Gtk::Entry*>(sigc::ptr_fun(&Handle), pText) );
    }                                                                    Here i have binded Entry widget with the signal_click so that it would be passed as argument to signal handler when button is clicked.